# What MS SQL Server types map to Types.VARCHAR

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, jtds

I'm working on a statement scanner for our updater (looking for statements that will cause problems with synchronized data) and I need to know which TSQL data types get resolved as [`Types.VARCHAR`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#VARCHAR) and which ones resolve to [`Types.LONGVARCHAR`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#LONGVARCHAR) when you invoke `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out: [Understanding the JDBC Driver Data Types in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378599(SQL.90).aspx):

- [Using basic data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878(SQL.90).aspx)
- [Using advanced data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813(SQL.90).aspx)

So basically:

- LONGVARCHAR: text, ntext, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), xml
- VARCHAR: varchar, nvarchar